# Al seleccionar un checkbox mostrar las opciones que contiene

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Me ha surgido la siguiente duda.

Tengo 2 checkbox que he mandado a traer desde mi BD en este caso todos los registros o son **BAJA O MEDIA**

```
<?php

  $gama = "SELECT DISTINCT (gama) FROM productos";
  $resulgama = mysqli_query($conexion,$gama) or die(msqli_error());

  while ($filasgama = mysqli_fetch_array($resulgama))
  {
    extract($filasgana);
    $outputgama_php.=<<<EOD
    <input type="checkbox" name=$gama>$gama
    <br>

    EOD;
  }
```

[image: Resultado de la consulta]

Pero ahora necesito que si selecciono **MEDIA** me muestre solo los modelos que tienen media gama
(los modelos de media gama son: A1, A3, DR5).

O de lo contrario si selecciono **BAJA** me muestre los modelos de baja gama.
(los modelos de baja gama son: E3, F4, FD4).

O que herramientas me sugieren usar.

Por su ayuda Gracias.

Comment: Sin javascript imposible.

Comment: Si claro, a lo que voy es que no conozco mucho del tema, si se requieren otras herramientas, esta bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede hacer con peticiones AJAX refrescando los options del select, pero mi recomendación es que uses una librería llamada select2.

El javascript te quedaría tal que así

```
$("#select-gama").select2({
                        placeholder: "Selecciona una opción",
                        language: "es",
                        width: '100%',
                        ajax: {
                            url: "/mi/ruta/gamas.php",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            delay: 250,
                            data: function (params) {
                                return {
                                    busqueda: params.term,
                                    tipo: $("#select-gama").val()
                                };
                            },
                            processResults: function (data) {
                                return {
                                    results: data
                                };
                            },
                            cache: true
                        },
                        templateResult: plantillaBusqueda,
                        templateSelection: plantillaSeleccionado
                    });

function plantillaBusqueda(gama) {
            return gama.nombre;
        }

function plantillaSeleccionado(gama) {
        if (gama.text != "") {
            return gama.text
        }
        return gama.nombre;
    }
```

y tendrías que hacerte un método en el controlador para gestionarla que traerá por parámetros "busqueda" y "tipo", donde búsqueda seria para filtrar por nombre y tipo para filtrar por BAJA o MEDIA y que devuelva un json con las opciones validas

[DOCUMENTACION SELECT2](https://select2.org/)